# How to convert from CMYK to RGB in Java correctly?

Tags: java, cmyk

My Java code to convert a CMYK jpeg to RGB results in the output image being far too light - see code below.  Can anyone suggest the correct way to do the conversion?

The following code requires [Java Advanced Image IO](https://jai-imageio.dev.java.net/) to read the jpeg and [example-cmyk.jpg](http://www.markmclaren.com/example-cmyk.jpg)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class TestCmykToRgb {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage cmykImage = ImageIO.read(new File(
                "j:\\temp\\example-cmyk.jpg"));


        BufferedImage rgbImage = new BufferedImage(cmykImage.getWidth(),
                cmykImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(null);
        op.filter(cmykImage, rgbImage);

        ImageIO.write(rgbImage, "JPEG", new File("j:\\temp\\example-rgb.jpg"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

There is a lot of good stuff in the existing answers already. But none of them is a complete solution that handles the different kinds of CMYK JPEG images.

For CMYK JPEG images, you need to distinguish between regular CMYK, Adobe CMYK (with inverted values, i.e. 255 for no ink and 0 for maximum ink) and Adobe CYYK (some variant with inverted colors as well).

This solution here requires Sanselan (or Apache Commons Imaging as it's called now) and it requires a reasonable CMYK color profile (.icc file). You can get the later one from Adobe or from eci.org.

```
public class JpegReader {

    public static final int COLOR_TYPE_RGB = 1;
    public static final int COLOR_TYPE_CMYK = 2;
    public static final int COLOR_TYPE_YCCK = 3;

    private int colorType = COLOR_TYPE_RGB;
    private boolean hasAdobeMarker = false;

    public BufferedImage readImage(File file) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
        colorType = COLOR_TYPE_RGB;
        hasAdobeMarker = false;

        ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader reader = iter.next();
            reader.setInput(stream);

            BufferedImage image;
            ICC_Profile profile = null;
            try {
                image = reader.read(0);
            } catch (IIOException e) {
                colorType = COLOR_TYPE_CMYK;
                checkAdobeMarker(file);
                profile = Sanselan.getICCProfile(file);
                WritableRaster raster = (WritableRaster) reader.readRaster(0, null);
                if (colorType == COLOR_TYPE_YCCK)
                    convertYcckToCmyk(raster);
                if (hasAdobeMarker)
                    convertInvertedColors(raster);
                image = convertCmykToRgb(raster, profile);
            }

            return image;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void checkAdobeMarker(File file) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
        JpegImageParser parser = new JpegImageParser();
        ByteSource byteSource = new ByteSourceFile(file);
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ArrayList segments = parser.readSegments(byteSource, new int[] { 0xffee }, true);
        if (segments != null && segments.size() >= 1) {
            UnknownSegment app14Segment = (UnknownSegment) segments.get(0);
            byte[] data = app14Segment.bytes;
            if (data.length >= 12 && data[0] == 'A' && data[1] == 'd' && data[2] == 'o' && data[3] == 'b' && data[4] == 'e')
            {
                hasAdobeMarker = true;
                int transform = app14Segment.bytes[11] & 0xff;
                if (transform == 2)
                    colorType = COLOR_TYPE_YCCK;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void convertYcckToCmyk(WritableRaster raster) {
        int height = raster.getHeight();
        int width = raster.getWidth();
        int stride = width * 4;
        int[] pixelRow = new int[stride];
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            raster.getPixels(0, h, width, 1, pixelRow);

            for (int x = 0; x < stride; x += 4) {
                int y = pixelRow[x];
                int cb = pixelRow[x + 1];
                int cr = pixelRow[x + 2];

                int c = (int) (y + 1.402 * cr - 178.956);
                int m = (int) (y - 0.34414 * cb - 0.71414 * cr + 135.95984);
                y = (int) (y + 1.772 * cb - 226.316);

                if (c < 0) c = 0; else if (c > 255) c = 255;
                if (m < 0) m = 0; else if (m > 255) m = 255;
                if (y < 0) y = 0; else if (y > 255) y = 255;

                pixelRow[x] = 255 - c;
                pixelRow[x + 1] = 255 - m;
                pixelRow[x + 2] = 255 - y;
            }

            raster.setPixels(0, h, width, 1, pixelRow);
        }
    }

    public static void convertInvertedColors(WritableRaster raster) {
        int height = raster.getHeight();
        int width = raster.getWidth();
        int stride = width * 4;
        int[] pixelRow = new int[stride];
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            raster.getPixels(0, h, width, 1, pixelRow);
            for (int x = 0; x < stride; x++)
                pixelRow[x] = 255 - pixelRow[x];
            raster.setPixels(0, h, width, 1, pixelRow);
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage convertCmykToRgb(Raster cmykRaster, ICC_Profile cmykProfile) throws IOException {
        if (cmykProfile == null)
            cmykProfile = ICC_Profile.getInstance(JpegReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/ISOcoated_v2_300_eci.icc"));

        if (cmykProfile.getProfileClass() != ICC_Profile.CLASS_DISPLAY) {
            byte[] profileData = cmykProfile.getData();

            if (profileData[ICC_Profile.icHdrRenderingIntent] == ICC_Profile.icPerceptual) {
                intToBigEndian(ICC_Profile.icSigDisplayClass, profileData, ICC_Profile.icHdrDeviceClass); // Header is first

                cmykProfile = ICC_Profile.getInstance(profileData);
            }
        }

        ICC_ColorSpace cmykCS = new ICC_ColorSpace(cmykProfile);
        BufferedImage rgbImage = new BufferedImage(cmykRaster.getWidth(), cmykRaster.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster rgbRaster = rgbImage.getRaster();
        ColorSpace rgbCS = rgbImage.getColorModel().getColorSpace();
        ColorConvertOp cmykToRgb = new ColorConvertOp(cmykCS, rgbCS, null);
        cmykToRgb.filter(cmykRaster, rgbRaster);
        return rgbImage;
    }
}


static void intToBigEndian(int value, byte[] array, int index) {
    array[index]   = (byte) (value >> 24);
    array[index+1] = (byte) (value >> 16);
    array[index+2] = (byte) (value >>  8);
    array[index+3] = (byte) (value);
}
```

The code first tries to read the file using the regular method, which works for RGB files. If it fails, it reads the details of the color model (profile, Adobe marker, Adobe variant). Then it reads the raw pixel data (raster) and does all the necessary conversion (YCCK to CMYK, inverted colors, CMYK to RGB).

**Update:**

The original code has a slight problem: the result was too bright. The people from the twelvemonkeys-imageio project had the same problem (see this [post](http://home.java.net/forum/topic/javadesktop/java-desktop-technologies/java-2d/colorconvertopicc-profile-issue?force=153)) and have fixed it by patching the color profile such that Java uses a perceptual color render intent. The fix has been integrated into the above code.

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting it. This was incredibly helpful. It is the first solution I have come across (not including other responses in *this* thread) which does a pretty decent job out of the box.

Comment: BTW: I've fixed the brightness issue in the mean time. See my update.

Comment: Cool, I cannot wait to try it out.

Comment: Wow, that looks much better! Wish I could up vote this answer again :)

Comment: Thanks, I took the code above and used a smaller ICC file from the CYMKDemo.jar here [LINK](http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2011/08/reading-cmyk-jpeg-images-with-java-imageio/) because I didn't need the 2Mb ECI one

Comment: Fabulous.  Any suggestions about to how to save a JPEG with the CMYK header (so that it would be in the format to benefit from being loaded into your library)?

Comment: @Codo your solution work great but i found that it actually reduced the image size considerably my image was 5 mb and converted image was 200 KB. Can you help - Virednra

Comment: I guess your talking about the file size of the JPEG images on disk (and not about the image size in memory). My code doesn't contain anything for saving as a JPEG image. So the difference might be due to the JPEG setting: CMYK and low compression for the source, RGB and high compression for the result.

Comment: The author renew CMYKDemo, so look here http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/

Answer (score 7):

I will copy my answer from the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858131/rgb-to-cmyk-and-back-algorithm/7636907#7636907):

In order to be displayed correctly CMYK images should contain [color space information](http://regex.info/blog/photo-tech/color-spaces-page1) as ICC Profile. So the best way is to use that ICC Profile which can be easily extracted with [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/):

```
ICC_Profile iccProfile = Sanselan.getICCProfile(new File("filename.jpg"));
ColorSpace cs = new ICC_ColorSpace(iccProfile);
```

In case there is no ICC Profile attached to the image, I would use [Adobe profiles](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=3680) as default.

Now the problem is that you cannot just load JPEG file with custom color space using ImageIO as it will fail throwing an exception complaining that it does not support some color space or sthing like that. Hense you will have to work with rasters:

```
JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
Raster srcRaster = decoder.decodeAsRaster();

BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(srcRaster.getWidth(), srcRaster.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster resultRaster = result.getRaster();

ColorConvertOp cmykToRgb = new ColorConvertOp(cs, result.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), null);
cmykToRgb.filter(srcRaster, resultRaster);
```

You can then use `result` wherever you need and it will have converted colors.

In practice, however I've come across some images (taken with camera and processed with Photoshop) that had somehow inverted color values so the resulting image was always inverted and even after inverting them once again they were too bright. Although I still have no idea how to find out when exactly to use it (when I need to invert pixel values), I have an algorithm that corrects these values and convert color pixel by pixel:

```
JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
Raster srcRaster =  decoder.decodeAsRaster();

BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(srcRaster.getWidth(), srcRaster.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster resultRaster = ret.getRaster();

for (int x = srcRaster.getMinX(); x < srcRaster.getWidth(); ++x)
    for (int y = srcRaster.getMinY(); y < srcRaster.getHeight(); ++y) {

        float[] p = srcRaster.getPixel(x, y, (float[])null);

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; ++i)
            p[i] = 1 - p[i] / 255f;

        p = cs.toRGB(p);

        for (int i = 0; i < p.length; ++i)
            p[i] = p[i] * 255f;

        resultRaster.setPixel(x, y, p);
    }
```

I'm pretty sure RasterOp or ColorConvertOp could be used to make conversation more efficient, but this was enough for me.

Seriously, there is no need to use these simplified CMYK to RGB conversion algorithms as you can use ICC Profile that is embedded into image or available for free from Adobe. Resulting image is going to look better if not perfect (with embedded profile).

Comment: the problem with the Adobe profiles is the license: "If the software is designed for use with an application software product (the "Host Application") published by Adobe, Adobe grants you a nonexclusive license to use such software with the Host Application only, provided you possess a valid license from Adobe for the Host Application. Except as set forth below, such software is licensed to you subject to the terms and conditions of the End-User License Agreement from Adobe governing your use of the Host Application."   

I'm not sure if it's allowed to use in this way?

Comment: There are free ICC color profiles on [eci.org](http://www.eci.org/de/downloads#icc-profile_der_eci). I can recommend ISO Coated v2 300% as a good general purpose profile.

Comment: This solution *will not work* in Java 7 and above, since the com.sun....JPEGImageDecoder  class' package is no longer available. Apparently it was bad practice to use com.sun... packages directly anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new open source library which supports CMYK processing.
All you need to do is to add the dependency to your project and a new reader will be added to the list of readers (while the known JPEGImageReader can't deal with CMYK).
You will probably want to iterate over these readers and read the image using the first reader which doesn't throw exception.
This package is a release candidate, but i am using it and it solved a huge problem that we had hard time dealing with.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twelvemonkeys.imageio/imageio-jpeg/

> EDIT: as stated in the comments, you can now also find a stable
>   release rather than RC.

You can do the iteration this way to get the BufferedImage, and after you got that, the rest is easy (you can use any existing image converting package to save it as another format):

```
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source)) {

        // Find potential readers
        Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

        // For each reader: try to read
        while (readers != null && readers.hasNext()) {
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();
            try {
                reader.setInput(input);
                BufferedImage image = reader.read(0);
                return image;
            } catch (IIOException e) {
                // Try next reader, ignore.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Unexpected exception. do not continue
                throw e;
            } finally {
                // Close reader resources
                reader.dispose();
            }
        }

        // Couldn't resize with any of the readers
        throw new IIOException("Unable to resize image");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

My sollution is based on a previous answer. I used "USWebCoatedSWOP.icc":

```
        //load source image
        JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(srcImageInputStream);
        BufferedImage src = decoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();
        WritableRaster srcRaster = src.getRaster();
        //prepare result image
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(srcRaster.getWidth(), srcRaster.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        WritableRaster resultRaster = result.getRaster();
        //prepare icc profiles
        ICC_Profile iccProfileCYMK = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream("path_to_cmyk_icc_profile"));
        ColorSpace sRGBColorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);

        //invert k channel
        for (int x = srcRaster.getMinX(); x < srcRaster.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = srcRaster.getMinY(); y < srcRaster.getHeight(); y++) {
                float[] pixel = srcRaster.getPixel(x, y, (float[])null);
                pixel[3] = 255f-pixel[3];
                srcRaster.setPixel(x, y, pixel);
            }
        }

        //convert
        ColorConvertOp cmykToRgb = new ColorConvertOp(new ICC_ColorSpace(iccProfileCYMK), sRGBColorSpace, null);
        cmykToRgb.filter(srcRaster, resultRaster);
```

In other words:

1. Open the image as BufferedImage.
2. Get its raster.
3. Invert the black channel in this raster.
4. Convert to rgb

Comment: JPEGImageDecoder uses a com.sun package, which is removed in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

CMYK to/fro RGB is difficult - you're converting between additive and subtractive colour. If you want an exact match, you need to look into per-device colour space profiles. What looks OK in one colour space usually doesn't when physically converted to another (i.e. proper CMYK output - not a naive preview on a monitor).

From my own experience, converting RGB to CMYK naively tends to result in a image that is too dark. Given that you report the opposite in the converse direction, there's probably an approximate brightness adjustment curve to be found which will do a fair job (but watch out for strange non-linearities within the colour space). If you have access to Photoshop I understand it has some sort of CMYK preview option which might speed up the process of figuring out such an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
    import java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace;
    import java.awt.color.ICC_Profile;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;


    public class ColorConv {
final static String pathToCMYKProfile = "C:\\UncoatedFOGRA29.icc";

public static float[] rgbToCmyk(float... rgb) throws IOException {
    if (rgb.length != 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ColorSpace instance = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(pathToCMYKProfile));
    float[] fromRGB = instance.fromRGB(rgb);
    return fromRGB;
}
public static float[] cmykToRgb(float... cmyk) throws IOException {
    if (cmyk.length != 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    ColorSpace instance = new ICC_ColorSpace(ICC_Profile.getInstance(pathToCMYKProfile));
    float[] fromRGB = instance.toRGB(cmyk);
    return fromRGB;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    try {
        float[] rgbToCmyk = rgbToCmyk(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rgbToCmyk));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cmykToRgb(rgbToCmyk[0], rgbToCmyk[1], rgbToCmyk[2], rgbToCmyk[3])));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```