# Java: How to work with CMYK image?

Tags: java, cmyk

I know that RGB is for monitors and CMYK is for printing, but I want to work with CMYK without any conversions. I want to upload a CMYK image (jpeg) and print it. But when I used 

`com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(is);
return decoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();`

I got an inversed colors image. How can I get the same image in CMYK?

Comment: Where did you get the `inversed colors image`, in paper (printed) or in your screen?

Comment: I got it in my screen.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to store image in CMYK and to display it also in my screen (user should see what he uploads) in CMYK?

Comment: refer to [that link](http://www.randelshofer.ch/blog/2011/08/reading-cmyk-jpeg-images-with-java-imageio/)

Comment: You can use my CMYK capable [JPEGImageReader](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg).

Answer (score 2):

There reason your colors are inverted is that you have a special variant of a CMYK JPEG image, namely Adobe CYYK. The strange colors are due to an old Photoshop bug (CMYK values are inverted) that has now become a de-facto standard that's handled by most JPEG software (except Java).

A proper CMYK conversion (handling different variants, using proper color profile etc.) can be found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132630/413337.