# Dealing with Adobe CMYK jpegs and Bufferedimage in java

Tags: java, adobe, bufferedimage, cmyk

Im trying to apply the code posted in this post:
[How to convert from CMYK to RGB in Java correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123574/how-to-convert-from-cmyk-to-rgb-in-java-correctly)
The Answer from the guy named Codo works for me so far, but my source is not a file, its an object that gets converted into a BufferedImage with

```
stream = (PRStream)object;
PdfImageObject image = new PdfImageObject(stream);
//this does not work
BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
```

The guy has a method that returns a BufferedImage from a file like so

```
public BufferedImage readImage(File file) throws IOException, ImageReadException
```

but i want to use

```
BufferedImage bi = readImage(image.getBufferedImage());
```

instead of

```
File f = new File("/Users/adlib/Documents/projekte/pdf_compress/envirement/eclipse_luna/WORKSPACE/PDFCompression/src/Bild.jpg");
BufferedImage bi = readImage(f);
```

cause im ectracting all the images from a pdf file using iText.
I messed around with the code (changed file to BufferedImage and added streams) but a just dont get it to work. The File as Input image works fine, but not really what i need. What do i need to change to get This guys code to work with BufferedImage as input for the readImage() method?

Here is the complete code of this guy
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12132630/4944643

He uses Sanselan / Apache Commons Imaging

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how iText extracts images, but chances are good it's using ImageIO. If so, you can just install (or depend on, using Maven) the [TwelveMonkeys JPEG ImageIO plugin](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#jpeg), and

```
BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
```

...should just work.

The above mentioned plugin does support CMYK (and Adobe YCCK) JPEGs.

If iText doesn't use ImageIO, the above won't work (ie. when you already have a `BufferedImage`, it's too late to make the correct conversion). You will instead need to get to the bytes of the underlying PDF (using the [`getImageAsBytes()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/parser/PdfImageObject.html#getImageAsBytes()) method), and use ImageIO (via the TwelveMonkeys JPEG plugin) to decode it:

```
byte[] imgBytes = image.getImageAsBytes();
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));
```

Comment: Did that allready. But i ended up getting an Image with Inverted colors.

Comment: @AlexP Ok.. As I'm the author of the plugin, I'm interested in investigating this if you like. Can you save the bytes from the `getImageAsBytes()` method to disk, and attach it to a new [issue](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues)?

Comment: This would be cool. But i dont know how to write the bytes from the getImageAsBytes to disk. Can you give me a little help?  never did that kind of stuff

Comment: @AlexP Try `File file = new File(yourPath); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file); try { out.write(image.getImageAsBytes()); } finally { out.close(); }` (sorry about the formatting, SO comments aren't great for code).

Comment: byte[] imgByte = image.getImageAsBytes();
               
                 Files.write(Paths.get("bytes.txt"), imgByte);
                 BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgByte)); like so?

Comment: Ok i did it your way. gonna attach that in a new isuue.

Comment: I'm sure your way works too. :-) Anyway, you might want to give the file a `.jpg` extension. Just because that is what the GitHub issue tracker likes. :-)

Comment: Done. Also uploaded an another jpeg with adobe cmyk but that one works fine and the colors turn out right in the resulting file